# How to export annotations in PDFTron?

Tags: flutter, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdftron

We are using pdfTron Flutter
We have been trying to export the highlights made by the user and Printing them in the console till now, we are going to export them into a text file but after solving this error

The error or I could say a strange behavior occurs with that method:
`var xfdf1 = await PdftronFlutter.exportAnnotations(null);`
it is supposed to export the XFDF format of all of the annotations in the PDF Document
Because of the null argument we passed in it

but actually, it does not perform its intended behavior but it randomly exports some annotations and the others are not exported
here are some Screenshots explaining what is actually happening
[image: Case 1]
You can notice here in the  tag of the XFDF format that only the second highlighted paragraph is exported ^^^^

[image: Case 2]
You can notice here that only the second paragraph is exported ^^^^

[image: Case 3]
here we tried to just highlight words, not paragraphs and u can notice that only the first word is exported in the content tag ^^^^

so could anyone please give us any hints or reasons on why does that happen
here is the code we are using if anyone has a recommendation or a better way to export the highlights we would be happy to hear it

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' show File, Platform;
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:mindfulreaders_app/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:pdftron_flutter/pdftron_flutter.dart';

class PDFViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Viewer(),
    );
  }
}

class Viewer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _ViewerState createState() => _ViewerState();
}

class _ViewerState extends State<Viewer> {
   FilePickerResult? result;
   late String _document;
   String _version = 'Unknown';
   bool _showViewer = true;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      initPlatformState();
      showViewer();
    }
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
  String version;
  try {
    PdftronFlutter.initialize("your_pdftron_license_key");
    version = await PdftronFlutter.version;
  } on PlatformException {
    version = 'Failed to get platform version.';
  }
  if (!mounted) return;

  setState(() {
     _version = version;
  });
}

void showViewer() async {
  result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
 );
 _document = result!.files.single.path!;
 if (result != null && result!.files.single.path != null) {
  await PdftronFlutter.openDocument(_document);
 }

 var path = await PdftronFlutter.saveDocument();
 print("flutter save: $path");

 var xfdf1 = await PdftronFlutter.exportAnnotations(null);
 print("Here is the annots");
 print(xfdf1);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: _showViewer
            ? DocumentView(
                onCreated: _onDocumentViewCreated,
              )
            : const HomePage()),
  );
}
void _onDocumentViewCreated(DocumentViewController controller) async {
  setState(() {
    _showViewer = !_showViewer;
  });
  await controller.openDocument(_document);
}
}
```

Comment: @KJ 
i really appreciate your response, but I do not need that collaborative environment it is a single user per session in our app
and by the way, I got the same problem stated in that question, the annotations are only visible when the pdf is opened  with pdfTron if, for example, if I opened an annotated pdf by pdftron using any other pdf viewer the annots do not exist 
we thought that there's some sort of hidden file that contains all of the annots of the PDF and it is only fetched by PDFtron when a PDF is selected to be opened

Comment: @KJ Thanks for response , i ve checked the file size before and after adding an annots 
and it is the same no change to it
could it be that the way we are saving the file is wrong ? 
would that affect the process of exporting the annots ?

Comment: @KJ 
also, i want to tell you that even if we thought about the way we are saving the PDF it's actually working correctly 
for example if i opened a PDF using PDFtron and added a puch of highlights 
then i closed the whole application 
and relaunched my application again to open that same PDF I added the punch annots to , those annots all of them are visible and not flattened 
but with any other pdf viewer or even PDFtron on another machine the annots are absent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253396/discussion-between-joegreen-and-k-j).

Comment: thanks for respons @KJ yes that is exactly what we want actually that simple act of user read or write

Comment: actually, it is not the first product we used we have tried using syncfusion_flutter pdf viewer and their implementation of applying highlights forces them to be flattened with the page content 
and we took a good dive in maybe 4 free opensource flutter pdfviewer package and all of them did not have the ability to just highlight a word

currently, we have sent our problem to pdftron support and actually I am surprised that they did not state any of the things u kindly said I really hope they would be able to give us a thrust to solve this issue or else I think we are going to let that idea go